Estimating Bessel Inequality for a Sequence of Functions Derived from a Frame in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
Let $ \{f_k(x)\} $ be a frame for $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. For those unfamiliar, a frame in a Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $ is a family of functions $ \{f_k\} \subset \mathcal{H} $ for which there exist constants $ A > 0 $ and $ B > 0 $ such that for all $ f \in \mathcal{H} $,
$$
A \| f \|^2 \leq \sum_k |\langle f, f_k \rangle|^2 \leq B \| f \|^2.
$$
In other words, a frame generalizes the concept of a basis, but allows for redundancy.
I am working with the following sequence of functions:
$$
\phi_k(t) = \int_t^{t+1} e^{-2\pi i x \xi} f_k(x) \, dx,
$$
where $ \xi \in \mathbb{R} $, and the frame $ \{f_k(x)\} \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. I would like to estimate a Bessel-type inequality for sums of the form
$$
\left\| \sum_k \alpha_k \phi_k(t) \right\|^2
$$
where $ \alpha_k \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ \sum_k |\alpha_k|^2 < \infty $. The norm is in $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $, so I am looking for a constant $ C $ such that
$$
\left\| \sum_k \alpha_k \phi_k(t) \right\|^2 \leq C \sum_k |\alpha_k|^2.
$$
In other words, I would like to bound the $ L^2 $-norm of the sum of the functions $ \phi_k(t) $ by the $ \ell^2 $-norm of the coefficients $ \alpha_k $.
I would appreciate any ideas or guidance on how to estimate such a constant $ C $.
Thank you in advance!
My attempt
The function $\phi_k(t)$ can be viewed as a smoothed and windowed version of the original frame elements $f_k(x)$. It is effectively the convolution of $f_k(x)$ with a characteristic function $\chi_{[t, t+1]}(x)$, modulated by the exponential $e^{-2 \pi i x \xi}$.
Since the norm of a convolution in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ can be controlled in terms of the norms of the individual functions, we can attempt to bound the norm of $\phi_k(t)$. Specifically, using Young's inequality for convolutions, the $L^2$-norm of $\phi_k(t)$ should be controlled by the $L^2$-norm of $f_k(x)$ multiplied by the norm of the characteristic function, which is simply 1 in $L^2([t, t+1])$. Hence,
$$
\left\|\phi_k\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \leq\left\|f_k\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
$$
... Now I don't know how to proceed further.
